# How do I convert NSUInteger value to int value in objectiveC?

Tags: ios, objective-c, int, nsuinteger

How do I convert `NSUInteger` value to `int` value in objectiveC?

and also how to print `NSUInteger` value in `NSLog` , I tried `%@,%d,%lu` these are not working and  throwing **Ex-Bad Access** error.

Thank you

Comment: It's `%lu`, not `@lu`.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

```
NSUInteger intVal = 10;
int iInt1 = (int)intVal;
NSLog(@"value : %lu %d", (unsigned long)intVal, iInt1);
```

for more reference, look [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html)

Comment: Apple's documentation (your link) explicitly states "Cast the value to unsigned long." for `NSUInteger`. So the last line should be `NSLog(@"the value is : %lu %d", (unsigned long)intVal, iInt1);`.

Answer (score 4):

Explicit cast to int

```
NSUInteger foo = 23;
int bar = (int)foo;
```

Although

```
NSLog(@"%lu",foo);
```

will work OK on current builds of OSX. It's not safe, as NSUInteger is typedeffed as unsigned int on other builds.  Such as iOS.  The strict answer is to cast it first:

```
NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)foo);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi all its working for me ...

I tried this..

```
NSUInteger  inbox_count=9;
NSLog(@"inbox_count=%d",(int)inbox_count);

//output   
inbox_count=9
```

thank to all..

Comment: Bad idea. On OSX, NSUInteger is long. So casting to int will overflow for large values.  It might be OK for iOS, but better to get used to doing it in a way that doesn't break on other builds.

Comment: @SteveWaddicor You have other problems when your inbox contains > 2 billion Mails.

Comment: The specifics of this case are not the limits of a stackoverflow answer.  Someone else may try to apply the broken code for a number that can get that big.  Better to do it right, when doing it wrong is no easier.

Comment: @SteveWaddicor I totally agree. It's just the specifics of this case that made me make this little joke.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple as this,

```
NSUInteger uintV = 890;
int intVal = (int) uintV;
NSLog(@"the value is : %lu", (unsigned long)intVal);
```

*this will print something like this,*
**the value is : 890**

Comment: Explain the down-vote please...